# $|G/J|=p \implies |J|=p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was solving a question when I faced with the following doubt: if $G$ is a group and $J\triangleleft G$ with $|G/J|=p$, can I say that $|J|=p$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $\vert G/J\vert = \vert G\vert / \vert J\vert$, so if $\vert J\vert=p$ then we have that $\vert G\vert = p^2$...

Comment: Do you know how quotients work? The underlying set of the quotient $G/J$ is a partition of $G$ into sets of size equal to $J$. In other words, $|G|=|G/J|\cdot|J|$, no different than usual numbers. What about this would suggest $|G/J|$ and $|J|$ are necessarily the same? Are $a/b$ and $b$ necessarily the same when $a,b$ are whole numbers?

Comment: Let's keep things constructive and civil, @anon.

Comment: @vadim123 I am usually *very* sensitive to non-constructive, uncivil comments, but to be honest, I didn't take anon's comment to be either of the two. I think anon is simply providing an analogy that might help minimize confusion re: notation, etc.

Comment: @anon, I was plunged in the question and I completely forgot Lagrange's theorem, I'm so sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group of order $p$ and let $J$ be the trivial subgroup. Then $|G/J|=|G|=p$ but $|J|=1$.

Comment: of course, of course stupid question, thank you for the help.